# Writing a research paper, and can't figure out the best way to say sentence

Tags: diction

Can I say

> *Receiving an insufficient amount of sleep* is an obstacle that may alter the performance of an individual.

Comment: *"Lack of sufficient sleep may have a detrimental effect on an individual's performance"* This is only one possible variant and as others have mentioned, you don't receive sleep.

Answer (score 1):

One doesn't "receive" sleep (who gives it?). *Getting* or *having* is better.

And although 'sufficient' is not wrong, I prefer the simpler 'enough'.

Try

> *Getting enough sleep*,

or

> *Ensuring that you have/get enough sleep*

Comment: Thank you for your help:)I meant insufficient...would it be better this way: Not getting enough sleep is an obstacle that may alter the performance of an individual.( this is my topic sentence that begins the paragraph btw

Comment: @user71587 That works for me, though you could replace 'alter' with *limit/impair/reduce* (assuming that is the case) and instead of 'the performance of an individual' use *an individual's performance* (a stylistic change only).

Comment: Exactly, "receiving" is wrong

Comment: Also for me it's not an "obstacle" - wrong word.  There might be an obstacle (sa .. "noisy neighbors") which gets in the way of you sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

*Receiving* **an insufficient** *amount of sleep is an obstacle that may alter the performance of an individual.*

Comment: I still would clean it up because an 'insufficient amount' of sleep may or may not be an obstacle to performance. When your claim is stated as a fact, your research paper needs to be statistically evidenced

Comment: hmmm...so it may be an obstacle that may alter...

Comment: obstacle is plain wrong.  you're using obstacle as "problem" or "issue".  an obstacle is an obstacle.  (heh)

Comment: Perhaps: An insufficient amount of sleep may impair an individual's performance.